# Differentiating an implicit equation.

Tags: derivatives

Google kind of failed me (since I really don't know how to ask it properly) in finding the answer to this question: how do I go about differentiating something like:

$$x^2y + xy^2 - y = 1$$

That is, I am interested in finding the $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}$ of the above equation? The basic methods or a finger in the right direction would be enough.

Comment: Typing "*derivative of (x^2)y + x(y^2) - y = 1*" into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) seems to do nicely (WA assumes you are looking for $\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x$).

Comment: I think what you're looking for is implicit differentiation.

Comment: The verb form of derivative is differentiate, not derivate.

Comment: Look up "implicit differentiation"

Comment: @avid19 Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Mike Pierce WA gives only the end-result, while I wanted some of the thought behind the solution.

Comment: Just wondering, would solving the equation for y using quadratic formula give the correct answer? You would get 2 functions of x though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Implicit differentiation and the product rule.  For example, if 
$y^2 + 2y + x = 0$, then differentiating gives $2y \frac{dy}{dx} + 2 \frac{dy}{dx} + 1 = 0$ and solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ gives the result.

Basically, treat the $y$ like an $x$ and every time you take the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, a $\frac{dy}{dx}$ appears.

As noted by Nicholas, we can also think of the chain rule.  If we look at how to implicitly differentiate an expression like $y^2$ (with respect to $x$, then the chain rule gives $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2) = \frac{d y^2}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = 2y \frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: I would suggest noting that the multiplied $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a direct consequence of the chain rule, so that the process of finding the answer is less mysterious.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, will do.

Answer (score 1):

Looks straightforward to me.  $d/dx(x^2y+ xy^2- y)= d/dx(1)$.

That reduces to d/x(x^2y)+ d/dx(xy^2)- d/dx(y)= 0$, and then $2xy+ x^2dy/dx+ y^2+ x d(y^2)/dx- dy/dx= 0$.  Can you finish that?